# DB population for Integration test server

Tags: java, database, automation, java-ee-6, setup-deployment

I am dealing with quite an interesting challenge, we have an integration project that needs to interconnect the "in development" application with legacy applications. We developed a proxy that calls the legacy application from the new application and now we need to test or development against the code of a third company. I order to do that we setup a server with the same setup as the productive server and we will connect the client application to this server for testing purposes.

Application rough involved technologies: Java EE 6, Postgresql, java 7, JPA 2, Hibernate, Jboss 7

My issue is that we need to populate the DB with pseudo-real data. Meaning data that can be generated and is appropriate from the point of view of the application. The data must be somehow real as it reacts to different notifications sent by the legacy applications suite via JMS. The concerns are that it should be simple, quick to implement and somehow to create a mechanism for easy reusage - whenever I need new data, just run it once (maybe with parameters?!) and the magic is done.

Currently I try to find the best approach, I considered the following up to know:

- plain SQL script
- java application that inserts the needed things in DB
- somehow exciting idea - use a scripting language to have the job done (which one - python, groovy)

Any idea, suggestion, question would be more than welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I order to populate the DB I built a tool on top of the application's public API that creates the needed entities. To make it easier for our customer to add the needed data I exposed appropriate methods as WS that can be called as wanted by the client.

I wrote the application in java, for subjective reasons, even if I consider that a scripting language - I suppose groovy - would've been the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use DBUnit it has an XLSImporter. So you can maintain your test data in an Excel file.

Comment: I will check that. Thank you.

Comment: In order to avoid maintaining an excel file, I decided to build a mini-utility application that introduces needed data in the DB.

Comment: I took a look over the DBUnit, works quite nice. I used XML import feature instead of the XLS, now I am looking for a way to integrate it properly.

Comment: What do you mean properly?

Comment: I mean, I need a way to call this from outside. WS or another way.

Comment: I usually use as a JUnit test. And make sure that maven runs it before the deploy / integration-test phase

Comment: I would do it also, but the server used is only used for this customer to check his implementation against ours. I should install maven to make populate the DB.